# Why is my docker container using high cpu, but my docker host is barely utilized?

Tags: docker, lxc, proxmox

I'm trying to understand the relationship between docker containers and their host machines.  My setup is as follows:

- Hypervisor: Proxmox (4x 10 core Xeon, 80 threads total)
- Docker Host: LXC on Proxmox, 40 cores allocated
- Docker Host OS: Ubuntu 22.10

**What I'm seeing:**

I have ~16 containers running within docker.  Most are utilizing a fraction of a percentage of a cpu as reported by docker stats.  One in particular is hovering around 100% utilization, sometimes spiking well above 100%.

When I look at the cpu utilization on the host lxc container, it's around 96% idle.  I'm confused as to why the docker container is running so 'hot' and not using more of the available hardware.  I've found a lot of documentation around setting limits, but not the opposite - which should be the default behavior.

Seeing as though the CPU is allowed to burst past 100%, I'm not seeing any performance type issues - but seeing that 100% having on my monitoring charts is bothering me:)

Any ideas of an action I can do to remediate this, or do I just leave it as-is?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue. I have a container that should cap the hosts processors. But it barely touches them, while docket stats shows the container at 99-100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `docker stats` show container CPU usage across all CPU cores, if your container is using 120% and the host has N cores, the average CPU usage per core is 120%/N.
Nothing to worry about unless one core is consuming 100%, check using `htop`

Answer (score -1):

You can limit the CPU use of the docker container, Use the following flag with the docker command

**--cpus="1.0"**

Example
`docker run --cpus="1.0" --name my_container <docker image name>`

Comment: This is the opposite of what I'm asking.  I know you can limit the amount of CPU that a container can use, I'm more asking why I have a container at 100% if I'm NOT limiting it, and I have a ton of unused CPU capacity available.